# What is the method to debug Android kernel from booting in tablet?

Tags: linux, bootloader, kernel, debug

I have to test a custom Android build on a tablet and I need to know the method to debug the Android kernel from booting in the tablet?

The tablet has only a screen, 2 USB ports and an HDMI port.

Comment: What do you mean by 'from booting'? Also this question comes close to a development one which would be better on StackOverflow.

Comment: I mean that i need to read the debug message since the boot stage

Comment: Have you tried to turn on USB-Debugging, and then after boot call `adb shell dmesg >boot.log`? As on Linux systems, this should store all messages from the device boot into a file called `boot.log`. // What is it you want to achieve? The more precise you are with your question, the more precise we can be with our answers :)

Answer (score 2):

Generally, what you need to achieve this is to connect to the serial console of the system. Like on a desktop system, this gives you all the kernel and init messages as the device boots, and access to a shell once the device has booted.

How to connect to the serial console varies between devices, and you haven't told us which device you have. Usually, you need to take the main board out of its case (this is irreversible in some devices, as you have to damage the case to get it open), and find the serial port. In most cases, there won't be any connector there, just exposed points on the motherboard to solder a connector or ribbon cable to. You need to find the datasheet for the device online to find the right point to connect to.

On some devices, the serial console is instead provided by connecting a special adaptor to the headphone jack. With a proper build of the kernel, the device can be made to send serial output on that connector, and you can connect to it with an adaptor you make yourself (if you can get the specifications from the manufacturer).

Comment: Interesting that serial console can be sent to headphone jack! mind giving more details? :)

Comment: I'm not sure I can give any more details, as I used this feature while working under NDA. It's a relatively recent thing, and requires hardware support.